# zurb foundation 4 grid issue with variables.scss

Tags: grid, zurb-foundation

I am working in the _variables.scss file and following your comments for set the value of $em-base to $base-font-size ($em-base: $base-font-size;)

i have done this `$em-base: $base-font-size;`

and i am getting a compile error in codekit because of this

Error is:  error style.scss (Line 192 of _global.scss: 7.68em*px/% isn't a valid CSS value.)
overwrite style.css

I'm doing all this because i want to have the correct grid size because I set my grid to 1320px & on the browser the row inspected says 990px

could you please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make sure that the value for $base-font-size is set to the value you want for you $em-base. Whatever you set for you em-base will be what calculates the width of things like the grid. So if you have a 16px $em-base, the em value for 82.5em for your row width.